# Django: dealing with non-ascii parameters

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm running into an issue dealing with non-ascii POST parameters. Here's a CURL request that shows the problem:

```
curl "http://localhost:8000/api/txt/" -d \
"sender=joe&comments=Bus%20%A3963.33%20London%20to%20Sydney"
```

The pound sign in `comments` is causing the issue: when I try to do just about anything with `request.POST['comments']` I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

For example, if I just try to log what `comments` is:

```
message = request.POST.get('comments', None)
file('/tmp/comments.txt', 'wb').write(message)
```

I get the above error. Or when I try to decode it, I get the same error:

```
try:
    message = message.decode('ISO-8859-2','ignore').encode('utf-8','ignore')
except Exception, e:
    file('/tmp/ERROR-decode.txt','w').write(str(e))
```

produces `ERROR-decode.txt` with:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`%A3` is wrong. It should in fact be `%C2%A3` or `%C5%81` in order to be correct UTF-8.

Also, ["Unicode In Python, Completely Demystified"](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

Comment: The request is coming to me from an external service, so I don't have  control over its contents. I did try testing with %C2%A3, and it just changes the error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' .

Comment: Well that's closer. Now just read that article to understand why.

Comment: Thanks Igancio. I've read that presentation many times now, and tried the .decode().encode() sequence as seen above. It gives the error mentioned above. Is there something beside .decode().encode I should try?

Comment: @Parand: No you haven't. How do I know? You still insist on decoding a `unicode`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass it first into urllib.unquote() to remove the quoting performed by HTTP, then, you can convert the string to unicode with the proper encoding

```
>>> unicode(urllib.unquote("Bus%20%A3963.33%20London%20to%20Sydney"), \
            "iso-8859-2").encode("utf-8") 
'Bus \xc5\x81963.33 London to Sydney'
```

Comment: Sorry Stefano, I didn't make it clear it was in the context of Django; django already unquotes the POST parameters for you, so 'comments' is an unquoted string already.

Comment: @Parand: ah ok. fair enough. then what you receive is a string which must be converted to unicode via the proper encoding. I use `unicode(str, "encoding")` which is clear in intent. Then you can `.encode()` this unicode object to utf-8 if you please.

Comment: No, what is received is a string that has already incorrectly been converted to a `unicode`, hence the presence of U+FFFD.